# How can I print the four corners of this array? and How do I find out if the columns are strictly ascending

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   ofstream outData;
   ifstream inData;
   string inString;
   int matrix[12][12];
   int rowSize, colSize;
   inData.open("C:\\Users\\JSU\\Documents\\ArrayInput.txt");

    inData >> rowSize >> colSize;
    cout << "Row= " << rowSize << "\t Col= "<<colSize<< endl;
    for (int r=0; r <rowSize; r++){
        for (int c=0; c <colSize; c++){
            inData >> matrix[r][c] ;
        }

    }
    // print the input values
    cout << "For the "<< rowSize << " x " << colSize << " array:"<<endl;
    for (int r=0; r <rowSize; r++){
        for (int c=0; c <colSize; c++){
            cout << matrix[r][c] << "  ";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout << endl<<endl;



    // find the largest in each row
    for (int c=0; c <colSize; c++){
        int largest = matrix[0][c]; //make the first cell value as the largest until you find otherwise 
        int smallest = matrix[0][c]; //make the first cell value as the smallest until you find otherwise 
        int sum=0;
        for (int r=0; r <rowSize; r++){
            if (matrix[r][c] > largest)   //found a new larger value than the largest
                largest = matrix[r][c];
            if (matrix[r][c] < smallest)   //found a new smaller value than the smallest
                smallest = matrix[r][c];
            sum = sum + matrix[r][c];

        }

        cout << "The sum of column "<< c + 1 << " is " << sum << endl; 
        cout << "The average of column "<< c + 1 << " is "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<< (double)sum/rowSize << endl;
        cout << "The largest value in column "<< c + 1 << " is " << largest << endl; 
        cout << "The smallest value in column "<< c + 1 << " is " << smallest << endl; 
        cout << "Is column " << c + 1 << " strictly ascending? " << endl;


        cout<<endl;
    }

    inData.close();
return 0;
```

}

This is my code, and I've done almost everything of what I need. I just can't figure out how to cout the four corners of the array, and I need to print something that says cout << "Is column " << c + 1 << " strictly ascending? " << endl; and I can't figure out how to make that work.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Printing Matrix Corners

Here is how to print the four corners of a matrix.
Note that the corners are at: (0,0), (0, MAX_COLUMNS), (MAX_ROWS, 0) and (MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLUMNS).

```
const unsigned int MAX_ROWS = 12U;
const unsigned int MAX_COLS = 12U;
unsigned int matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
//...
cout << matrix[0][0] << endl;
cout << matrix[MAX_ROWS][0] << endl;
cout << matrix[0][MAX_COLS] << endl;
cout << matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] << endl;
```

### Ascending Column Values

By definition, a column has ascending values if column[n] < column[n + 1].
Implementing this in a `for` loop:

```
bool is_ascending = true;
for (unsigned int col = 0;
     (col < MAX_COLS-1) && is_ascending;
     ++col)
{
  if (matrix[row][col] >= matrix[row][col + 1])
  {
    is_ascending = false;
  }
}
```

You may want to adjust the rule and let equal items count as ascending values.

Answer (score 0):

The corners of an two dimensional array can be obtained as follows:
let an array a be = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} Then the corner elements of the example array would be 1,3,7 and 9.
So, our Program would be like:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        if(i%2==0||j%2==0)
        cout << a[i][j];
        else
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```